# Ignoring Scala scripts when using sbt compile server in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IDEA brought in an external compile server using sbt fairly recently.

I have a bunch of `.scala` scripts sitting alongside other Scala source files in one of my projects. I just rebuilt the project for the first time since this new compile server came in, and attempting to compile comes up with `Error(1, 1) expected class or object definition` (since scripts are just a list of commands / definitions and not enclosed in an object or class).

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the script files?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.sc` and IDEA won't be complaning.

**Updated.**

Another way is to use `.sh` extension as a shell script, like proposed [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166) in *Script It!* part

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Yes, you r right, but it is a bug in IDEA. It was discussed somewhere on github, and `.sc` was proposed as an actual solution to the problem

Comment: OK, but I tried it and IDEA interprets them as worksheets, which is not what I want. edit: ah, I see, you say it's an IDEA bug

Comment: Even better, drop the suffix entirely! The whole point of "scripts" in the Unix world is that the user does not need to know they're not native code, so their name should not disclose that detail. I write gazillions of BASH scripts and never, ever give their name a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Use another extension for script files, not `.scala` and not `.sc`, for instance it could be `.scalas`, to have highlighting and CodeCompletion append it to Scala's File Types:

```
File -> Settings -> File Types -> Scala Files
```